# How to track leap second change after it happened?

Tags: linux, rhel, date

I had applied a patch from Redhat on this machine to automatically correct the [leap second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) change by inserting an extra second at the time of leap second change. Now, I want to see its effect. Of course, I could see an entry in the system logs which clearly tells that the change was applied:

```
grep "leap" /var/log/messages
Jan  1 05:29:59 mymachinename kernel: Clock: inserting leap second 23:59:60 UTC
```

But, is there a way to visualize it in a way something like this:

```
  2011-12-31 23.59.57
  2011-12-31 23.59.58
  2011-12-31 23.59.59
  2011-12-31 23.59.60 <-- leap second
  2012-01-01 00.00.00
  2012-01-01 00.00.01
  2012-01-01 00.00.02
```

Creating a `watch` to write output of `date` every second to a file and executing it minutes before the leap second change in our timezone would serve this requirement. But in my case it is of no help because leap second change has already happened and I missed to create a `watch`. Is there any way to produce system date history so that I can see this change there?

I am sure that the change was applied and this question is to visualize its effect. Any help is much appreciated.